# download a file with curl command using Popen subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, curl, subprocess, popen

I am using curl command to download a file and popen subprocess  to run that command .
i want to control the limit rate of downloading to 50mps.

when i run below commad in terminal, it works fine.

```
curl -o down.tar.gz --limit-rate 50M http://localhost:5000/download
```

but when i run Popen to run that command in pycharm like below,

```
Popen(['curl', '-o', 'down.tar.gz','--limit-rate 50M', 'http://localhost:5000/download'])
```

then it gives me error as shown below,

```
curl: option --limit-rate 50M: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

How i can use curl with limit rate in Popen ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Popen` is called with a list, the arguments are not split further. So your code is passing the whole `--limit-rate 50M` as a single argument to `curl`.

You need to split the option & option-value in the command token list like so:

```
Popen(['curl', '-o', 'down.tar.gz','--limit-rate', '50M', 'http://localhost:5000/download'])
```